# elasticsearch python script plugin in Update API

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to run a simple update script in elasticsearch.
It seems to work fine with mvel, but not with python.

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/index1/type1/1/_update?pretty=true' 
-d '{"script" : "ctx._source.myfield=\"item\""}'
{
  "ok" : true,
  "_index" : "index1",
  "_type" : "type1",
  "_id" : "1",
  "_version" : 7
}

curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/index1/type1/1/_update?pretty=true' 
-d '{"script" : "ctx._source.myfield=\"item\"","lang":"python"}'
{
  "error" : "ElasticSearchIllegalArgumentException[failed to execute script]; nested: NullPointerException; ",
  "status" : 400
}
```

my ES version is 0.20.4

my elasticsearch-lang-python plugin is  1.1.0 ( i also tried with 1.2.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [a bug](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-lang-python/issues/4) in python plugin. You can add empty parameter list as a workaround:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/index1/type1/1/_update?pretty=true' -d '{
    "script": "ctx[\"_source\"][\"myfield\"]=\"foo\"",
    "lang": "python",
    "params": {}
}'
```